# Disable href and execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<a href="link.cshtml">
    <div>...</div>
    <div class="function">...</div>
    <div>....</div>
</a>
```

I would like disable href on div with class function and call a function when I click on this div.

I have tried with `onclick="return false; testFunction();"` but obviously it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Of course it doesn’t work in _that_ order ... nothing _after_ a return statement gets executed.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: use `event.preventDefault();`  inside testfunction() to prevent the default action of hyperlink click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should use the `preventDefault` to make sure the browser will not run the default `href`.
2. If you `return` - nothing will run after that...

```js
function testFunction() {
  alert('hi');
}
document.querySelector('.function').addEventListener('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  testFunction();
});
```

```html
<a href="https://www.yahoo.com">
    <div>...</div>
    <div class="function">Click here will not change page</div>
    <div>....</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make it is with `javascript:void(0)` and click event via jquery

```js
$(".function").click(function(){
 console.log("test")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">
    <div>...</div>
    <div class="function">Click here will not change page</div>
    <div>....</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selector').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Cool!");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this :

```
$('#content a').click(function(){ return false });
```

Returning `false` from the click event handler prevents the default behavior (following the link).

If you may have more than one link but you want to disable only this one, you may be more specific in your selector :

```
$('#content a[href="/test/"]').click(function(){ return false });
```